# Java code for SSL not recognizing SAN

Tags: java, ssl

I have a domain name like `xyx.com`, and I created a sub domain as well such like `dev.xyz.net`.

We bought a 3 sub-domain SSL certificate from an authority and I added `dev.xyz.net` in the sub domain.

Our site is hosted on Azure and I attached the certificate to it.

We then tried to make an API call to the REST API from Java code and REST API. But we keep getting this error:

```
I/O error on POST request for (https) xyz.net: Certificate for <xyz.net> doesn't match any of the subject alternative names: [*.azurewebsites.net, *.scm.azurewebsites.net, *.azure-mobile.net, *.scm.azure-mobile.net]; nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Certificate for <xyz.net> doesn't match any of the subject alternative names: [*.azurewebsites.net, *.scm.azurewebsites.net, *.azure-mobile.net, *.scm.azure-mobile.net]
```

I am not sure what the above means? How could I add azure as sub domain?

Comment: My guess is that this is not the certificate you like to see and you got it because your code is missing the SNI extension. More details can not be given since your code and Java version are unknown but there are lots of posts regarding [Java SNI](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+sni+site%3Astackoverflow.com)

Comment: just for the sake of debugging, did you try accessing the api endpoint in your browser?

Comment: yes and it works with python, .NET etc